# Multiplication macro gives the wrong answer

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MULTIPLY(a, b) a*b

int main(){
    cout << MULTIPLY(2+3, 3+5);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected this to print `40` since five times eight is forty. Why does it print `16`?

Comment: `2 + 3 * 3 + 5` is not 40.

Comment: Try this instead `#define MULTIPLY(a, b) ((a)*(b))` and think about what the difference is.

Comment: But even better than any macros `int MULTIPLY(int a, int b) { return a * b; }`.  Macros are The Devil™.

Comment: Don't use macros. Just don't.

Comment: A good illustration why Macros are bad:  `MULTIPLY(4, "Hello");`  If `MULTIPLY` was a function, the compiler would catch it.

Comment: Just use a *proper function* - why wouldn't you?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Why would the compiler not catch it in a macro? That should not compile.

Answer (score 5):

Because C++ macros are not functions. They are text copies, so that means:

```
cout << 2+3*3+5;
```

Which is 2 + (3*3) + 5